# Creating the celestial sphere for astronomical demonstrations

Tags: graphics3d, astronomy

Quick question: has anybody produced (and/or willing to produce and share) a nice celestial sphere with some stars and/or constellations? 
I am traveling , so I cannot do it myself right now, but I would get the coord. of the 10 brightest stars and/or some constellation data from W/A and then put them on a sphere together with some ref. points/circles (equator, ect).

Comment: You can check here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=celestial

Comment: Thank you @MarkusRoellig, I am checking them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just show you how to put visible stars on a sphere in proportion to their "ApparentMagnitude".

```
data = EntityValue[
   EntityClass["Star", "NakedEyeStar"], {"RightAscension", 
    "Declination", "ApparentMagnitude"}];

t = With[{m = 
     MinMax[data[[All, 3]]]}, {-QuantityMagnitude[#[[1]], "Radians"], 
      QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]], "Radians"], 
      Rescale[Round[#[[3]]], m, {1, .1}]} & /@ data];
g = GatherBy[t, #[[3]] &];
s = With[{r = 1}, {PointSize[#[[1, 3]]*.01], 
      Point[{-r Cos[#[[1]]] Sin[#[[2]] + Pi/2], 
          r Sin[#[[1]]] Sin[#[[2]] + Pi/2], -r Cos[#[[2]] + 
             Pi/2]} & /@ #]}] & /@ g;
Graphics3D[{{Yellow, s}, {Blue, Opacity[0.75] , Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Very nice, thank you Alex.